# React Native How to show an element above bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to show a media player above the bottom tab navigator just like in spotify app.
It should stay there in same state across all the screens (bottom tabs).

[image]

Any suggestions or approaches to implement this in React native ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use an React.Context as you wanna show the same object (music control panel) on each screen with same state and not an replica on each screen.

For positioning I suggest using an `absolute` position. This works together with "react-navigation" because header and bottom areas are changed.
This means `bottom:0` is no longer the screens bottom within a tab navigator it's right above the TabBar.

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/tab-floating-snack-bar?platform=android):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MusicControlPanelContext, MusicControlPanelConsumer } from './components/MusicControlContext';
import {MusicControlPanel} from './components/MusicContorlPanel'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
      <MusicControlPanelConsumer/>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
      <MusicControlPanelConsumer/>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MusicControlPanelContext.Provider value={MusicControlPanel}>
      <>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
              activeTintColor: '#000000',
              inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
              activeBackgroundColor: '#ff0000',
              inactiveBackgroundColor: '#ff0000',
              style: {
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
              },
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </>
    </MusicControlPanelContext.Provider>
  );
}


import * as React from 'react';
import { MusicControlPanelContext } from './MusicControlPanelContext';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function MusicControlPanelConsumer() {
  return (
   
    <MusicControlPanelContext.Consumer>
      {(Component) => <Component/>}
    </MusicControlPanelContext.Consumer>
    
  );
}

export { MusicControlPanelConsumer };


import * as React from 'react';
import {MusicControlPanel} from '../MusicContorlPanel'

export const MusicControlPanelContext = React.createContext<React.FC>(MusicControlPanel);


import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Pressable } from 'react-native';

export const MusicControlPanel: React.FC = () => {
  const [startStop, setStartStop] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '90%',
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#ff00ff',
        bottom: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() =>
          setStartStop((val) => {
            return !val;
          })
        }>
        <Text>{startStop ? 'Start' : 'Stop'}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice ans elaborate explanation, but in your snack example I'am seeing Start -> Stop on home screen doesn't reflect on the settings screen, there its still Start and vice versa.

State is not in sync across screens, can we fix it? rest of the solution is awesome!

Comment: Not re-rendering on state update across screens

Answer (score 7):

I just solved this problem

- import BottomTabBar
- call tabBar props in tab navigator
- wrap it with empty tag
- import and insert your component above the BottomTabBar

```js
import { BottomTabBar } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';  
import SmallVideoPlay from 'YOUR_PATH_OF_THE_COMPONENT';

<Tab.Navigator 
    tabBar={(props) => (
        <>
            <SmallVideoPlay />
            <BottomTabBar {...props} />
        </>
    )}
>
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={Home}/>
    {/* .... */}
</Tab.Navigator/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate the height of Bottom Navbar and make a View with Position:'absolute' and to keep it above Bottom Navbar assign the height of Navbar to 'bottom' of this View.

```
   <View>
  <View
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      backgroundColor: "#4470AE",
      bottom: 75,
      flexDirection: "row",
      width: "90%",
      height: 60,
      paddingVertical: "3%",
      alignSelf: "center",
      borderRadius: 12,
      margin: "3%",
    }}
  ></View>
  <View
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      backgroundColor: "orange",
      bottom: 0,
      height: 75,
      flexDirection: "row",
      width: "100%",
      justifyContent: "space-around",
      paddingVertical: "3%",
      borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    }}
  >
  </View>
</View>
```

[image: Adding a Sample Screenshot of this approach]

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 Solution - How to show an element or component above the "bottom Tab Navigator" in React Native?

Create a Fragment and place your component "FooterRadioPlayer" **UNDER** the Tab.Navigator's

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import FooterRadioPlayer from "../../FooterRadioPlayer"

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

          <>
            <Tab.Navigator
              initialRouteName="Home"
              screenOptions={() => ({
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: "#000000",
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#C4C4C4",
                tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
              })}
            >
              <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeStackScreen}
                options={{
                  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
                    !focused ? (
                      <HomeIcon style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                    ) : (
                      <ActiveHomeIcon style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                    ),
                }}
              />
              <Tab.Screen
                name="Search"
                component={SearchStackScreen}
                options={{
                  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
                    !focused ? (
                      <SearchIcon style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                    ) : (
                      <ActiveSearchIcon style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                    ),
                }}
              />
            ...
            </Tab.Navigator>
            <FooterRadioPlayer />
          </>
```

Then in your component stylesheet, align it to your desire.

```
footerRadioPlayer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    width: "100%",
    bottom: 55,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
```

## Final Result

[image: Footer Player Above the Bottom Tab Navigator]

Hopefully this gives a different solution...